# Correlation matrix for 1 Response Variable and 34 Dependent Variables

Tags: r, correlation

I am working with a dataset that contains 35 variables. I would like to determine the correlation just between the dependent variable and independent variables only, however, I can't seem to find any information on how to do this plus a correlation matrix produces a 35x35 matrix.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply take the row of the correlation matrix corresponding to your answer? You could also loop over each of the independent variables, get the correlation with your outcome and save that out. That would produce a 34-length vector that seems to be what you are interested in.